# App Store list of supported devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I designed my game app for iPhone 4 and higher with retina display, it also supports iPad
I want to limit to iPad2+, iPhone4+(iPhone 3GS the biggest problem, I could just limit by iOS version).
I think that DeviceCapabilities is what I need, is it?
Will my app be rejected if I use "front-facing-camera" key (I do not use camera in app, I just want to limit the list of supported devices.)?

May be some other advices what should I do or specify?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats wrong with support for iOS 6 and up ?

Comment: iOS6 supports iPhone 3GS

Comment: You can't select a list of devices to run on (or in sharpest other words downloadable) on the AppStore/itunesConnect.
The only way is too change the iOS version your App supports, then some device may not be able to run on.
Means you have to write, like others games on AppStore "Not compatible with iPhone 3GS" or whatever, even if users can download it, and then, see them shot at you that it doesn't work on this version ^^

Comment: You can use API to check if they have certain hardware or not and then exit the  app if they don't support that hardware and mention that in your app description.

Comment: iPhone 3GS, in my case, doesn't show required frames-per-second.

Comment: @bobenko so you should paraphrase your question to address this specific problem in iPhone 3GS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limiting with "front-facing-camera" is ok. Even if you don't use camera.

Answer (score 1):

If you set minimum Target to iOS7 only the listed Devices will get it(iPhone 4+,iPad 2+)
But you can't install it on devices with iOS < 7

Comment: But I do not want to limit to iOS7 only

Comment: Ok so thats not an Option - sorry